# c++ set::find by object property

Tags: c++, qt, boost, dictionary, unordered-map

I have an `object` with a `property`, which is required for methods of this object:

```
class Object {
   Property property;
}
```

Then I need to group this object. It is required that in this group there are objects only with unique properties. It is natural to group this objects in `set`. I define a `operator<` or if it is `unordered_set` `operator==` and `hash()`. It is ok. Then another problem arises. I need to find this objects in set using `property`. So I need to create an object of type `Object` an assign this property to its field. And this is what I don't like here.

Another approach is to make a `map`. And copy or make pointers to properties of objects and then use them as keys in a map. I think it is also a double work.

I want something like `set`, but with capability to make searches not using a whole object, but using a property of an object to find it. For, example, I define the following:

```
class Object {
   Property property;
   bool operator<(Object obj) { return property < obj.property; }
   bool operator<(Property obj) { return property < obj.property; }
};
some::set<Object> objSet;
```

then I can do the following:

```
Object obj;
objSet.insert(obj);
objSet.find(obj.property);
```

Could u offer some implementation of a container which helps me? boost, qt are acceptable.

Comment: How is `operator<` defined? Does it use the `property` as the main criterion?

Comment: Yes `operator<`, `operator==`, `hash()` use only `property` field.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/) is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 4-parameter overload of [std::equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range), providing a comparator that compares a `Property` with an `Object`.

```
struct Cmp
{
    bool operator() ( const Object& o, const Property& p ) const
    {
        return o.property < p;
    }
    bool operator() ( const Property& p, const Object& o ) const
    {
        return p < o.property;
    }
};

std::set<Object> s = ....;
Property property_val = ....;
auto r = std::equal_range(s.begin(),s.end(), property_val, Cmp());
```

Another option is to use `std::find_if` with a suitable unary predicate. But you wouldn't benefit from the logarithmic lookup of `std::set` or `std::equal_range`.

Comment: Thank you. But `std::find_if` and `std::equal_range` are more like features of `std` to hide routine code, but not an implementation of containers. As u said this features ruins containers' benefits for searching.

Comment: @user14416 `std::equal_range` is OK, it has logarithmic complexity. Maybe I will put it first.

Answer (score 5):

[Boost Multi-Index array](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/) could be what you need. This example [multiple sort on a single set](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort) is pretty match what ayou are looking for.

```
typedef multi_index_container<
  Object,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<member<Object,Property,&Object::property> >
  > 
> object_set;

object_set oset;
Property prop;
oset.find( prop );
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd opt for [Boost Multi Index](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/)

You can even define a key extractor and index from Property if needed if the value isn't exposed directly. (I made Property a struct and Object public for easy printing but as long as Property::get_value() is public this would work)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct by_property_value{};
struct byseq{};
struct by_id{};

struct Property{
    int value;
    std::string name;

    int get_value() const{
        return value;
    }
};

class Object {
public:
   int id;
   Property property;
};

Object make_object(const int&id, const int& value, const std::string& name){
    Object res;
    res.id = id;
    Property p;
    p.value = value;
    p.name = name;
    res.property = p;
    return res;
}

bool operator<(const Object& lhs, const Object& rhs){
    return lhs.id < rhs.id;
}



using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct property_value_key_extractor{
    typedef int result_type;

    result_type operator()(const Object& o) const{
        return o.property.get_value();
    }
};

typedef multi_index_container<
    Object,
    indexed_by<
        sequenced<tag<byseq> >
        , ordered_unique<tag<by_id>,member<Object,int,&Object::id> >
        , ordered_non_unique<tag<by_property_value> , property_value_key_extractor >
    >
> Objects;


using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Objects objects;
    objects.push_back(make_object(1,1000,"a"));
    objects.push_back(make_object(2,200,"b"));
    objects.push_back(make_object(3,50,"c"));

    typedef Objects::index<by_property_value>::type objects_by_property_value;
    typedef objects_by_property_value::iterator property_value_iterator;

    property_value_iterator it = objects.get<by_property_value>().find(200);

    if(it != objects.get<by_property_value>().end()){
        cout << it->id << " " << it->property.get_value() << " " << it->property.name << endl;
    }

    cout << "Print by propety value" << endl;

    for(property_value_iterator it = objects.get<by_property_value>().begin(); it != objects.get<by_property_value>().end(); it++ ){
        cout << it->id << " " << it->property.get_value() << " " << it->property.name << endl;
    }

}
```

Outputs:

> 2 200 b
>   Print by propety value
>   3 50 c
>   2 200 b
>   1 1000 a